# Page layouts with embedded column references and webparts - upgradade implications 2007 to 2010?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, layout, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I've got a 2007 SharePoint site with some custom page layouts which have custom controls for webparts and editable content columns. We're due to upgrade to MOSS 2010, but I'm not sure about the implications for the page content which relies on these layouts.

The Page Library should migrate successfully, so our data will be intact, but I could do with some help understanding these two issues please!

1. MOSS 2010 comes with new layouts. We'll need to customise these as required to meet our new designs, but how do we then insert our web controls to link them back to the columns in the Pages library? Is it as simple as copying the following 2007 code snippet into the 2010 layout file?

   ```
   <SharePointWebControls:Notefield FieldName="Comments" runat="server" id="NoteField20" CssClass="ArticleEditMode"></SharePointWebControls:NoteField>
   ```

   - In this scenario we'd presumably need to edit all the pages individually and re-assign them to our new layout?
   - Will all the Pages in the library then instantly spring to life and display things correctly?
2. How will the same situation play out with the webparts placed onto the layout page? All will be created against the corresponding webpart zone code in the layout file, and whatever webpart was placed manually on the layout itself.

   ```
   <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="Right Column" ID="TopRightRow"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
   ```

   - Again, do we simply need to copy the webpart code over, and then re-import the webpart into the layout to get it appearing across all pages?

Answer (score 0):

Any SharePointWebControls will continue working on 2010 (they are just the visual rendering of the edit mode and display mode of the data within your list items) but to be able to rely on 2010 native (or customize) page layouts, you'll need to update your UIVersion to 4.0 and switch to a native 2010 master page (or a customized one if you had custom contentplaceholders in the 3.0 edition).

If you had not so customized master page / page layouts / content types, the upgrade process might be smooth otherwise, it might be better to continue in v3 mode

I'd rather update your page layouts that will be deployed to the master page gallery to progressively include v4 specific rendering rather than detaching the page layout association and picking another one.

Finally, in order to successfully start to upgrade your 2007 installation to 2010, you can rely on the visual upgrade guide : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg454789.aspx 
and to upgrade your master page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539981.aspx

As a side remark, the 2010 UI isn't the holy grail and as soon as you start to heavily customized it, you'll see it's limits so it might be better to freshen your 2007 UI and rely on 2010 new functionnalites rather than fully (visually) upgrade to 2010.

Kindly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Francois, so it sounds like the process of creating new v4 layouts should be smooth - we'll be able to recreate the functionality we currently have without having to recode the entire system. Do you know of a way to assign multiple pages to a layout without having to edit them one by one?

Comment: That sounds like a sweet proposal for a short powershell script. You can easily loops in AllWebs and if you have a page library, you do a systemUpdate of each item requiring an update of its page layout property (even easier if you just target a specific page library). Otherwise you use something like this : http://splistitemeditor.codeplex.com/ on the target environment and you do some manual batch update in a excel like view :)